# Iterating over $\{0,1\}^n$ up to symmetry

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have a function $Q:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I wish to evaluate $Q$ at all corners of the $n$-dimensional unit cube (the points with every coordinate $0$ or $1$).

This is easy: loop through all integers from $0$ to $2^n$, convert to binary, use that as a coordinate.

$Q$ has a number of symmetries that I would like to exploit. I know one or several matrices [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $M_s$ such that $Q(M_s v)=Q(v), v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. So I should not have to calculate $2^n$ cases, but rather $2^{n-S}$ cases, with $S$ the number of symmetries.

Given one or several permutation matrices $M_s$, is there some simple way of iterating over $\{0,1\}^n$ "up to symmetry"? In other words, to iterate over the smallest subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ from which $\{0,1\}^n$ can be generated by (possibly repeatedly) multiplying by $M_s$?

Answer (score 0):

Construct the  [hypo-octahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group) and then filter for the symmetries. The group in n dimensions can possibly be constructed from the group in n-1 dimensions (in a permutation representation) by taking the (0,1) representations of the corners in n-1 dimensions, copying them with an additional 0 and 1, and requiring (as generators) that the additional symmetry planes (one for each pair of surfaces) exist.

Comment: This answer is beyond my grasp of group theory.